# Simple htaccess renamed page rewrite is not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have trawled the web for an answer to what I think should be a very simple problem but cannot find an exact match to my problem. I have a site that uses a bunch of rewrite rules in an htaccess file, eg:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html#([^/]+)$ index.php?pageid=$2#$3 [L]
```

My customer has asked for some page name changes so what was news/25.html is now latest-news/25.html. My concern is search engine indexing so I tried adding each of following to my htaccess file, all result in a 404 page:

```
RewriteRule ^news/25.html$ latest-news/25.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/25\.html$ latest-news/25\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/news/25\.html$ /latest-news/25\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/25\.html$ https://www.domainname/latest-news/25\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/25.html$ https://www.domainname/latest-news/25.html [R=301,L]
```

I have tried adding before and after my main rewrite rules.

Comment: Your current of matching `#` and part after that won't work at all because browsers don't send `#` and anything after `#` to web server.

Comment: the rewrite rule that includes # are constructed for when there is a page anchor appended to the url, these pages work fine. The renamed pages are the rewrites that fail.

Comment: Not sure if you understood what @anubhava explained... Your current rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html#([^/]+)$ index.php?pageid=$2#$3 [L]` does not make any sense: the _first_ of the two "#" in there can't ever match anything.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it, I wish I had not posted the rewrite rule that included the #'s, it's the only one of its kind and not causing the problem. It's one of the first rule in the file and the following and more important rules all work fine.
The problem I have is with the renamed page rewrites, why would they cause a 404 error?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are getting a 404 for the originally requested URL because it doesn’t perform the rewrite (and not the other way around, it rewrites, but then the _new_ URL results in a 404)? // Try and check your full .htaccess using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, and see what that has to say.

Comment: Thanks, a nice resource. My rules get the green light on madewithlove. I tested the rewrites used across the site (which are working fine), all good. I tested the rewrite that I'm getting the 404 from, it also gets the green light but on the site I get redirected to the custom 404. I have rules in the htaccess for a custom 404, I tried remove them but that did not work. I completely stumped.
My standard rewrites (without the #) are as follows:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?pageid=$2 [L]
If I add:
RewriteRule ^news/5.html$ index.php?pageid=5 [L]
I still get a 404 error?

Comment: Finally got this working, it does not work as a 301 so a canonical tag will be needed on the renamed address. I had to add the page id as an expression: RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?pageid=$1 [L]